# i'm stuck how to access name element from API in my react project, i've given snapshot of API and my code below can anyone please help me

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function Shop() {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const fetchItems = async() => {
    const data = await fetch('https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get');
    const items = await data.json();
    console.log(items.data);
    setItems(items.data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <h1>{item.name}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

i'm unable to access name element from API

*snapshot of API in console log given below *][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3s9b.jpg)

Comment: Just try console.log(data); because is already in json format . if you want to access items try:  console.log(data.data?.item);

Comment: Huh @Timmy? `data` will be a fetch response object - it's just a bad name for the variable

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the data, each element in the array has a property called `item`, that has a property called `name`

So you want

```
<h1>{item.item.name}</h1>
```

in full that would be

```
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <h1>{item.item.name}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

mapybe you could use as different name for the callback argument

```
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(element => (
        <h1>{element.item.name}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

or even

```
  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(({item}) => (
        <h1>{item.name}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

```js
const fetchItems = async() => {
  const res = await fetch('https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get');
  const items = await res.json();
  return items.data;
};
// testing if items would be what is required
(async() => {
  const items = await fetchItems();
  const result = items.map(({item}) => item.name);
  console.log(result);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(
      "https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get"
    );
    const items = await data.json();
    setItems(items.data);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item, i) => (
        <h1 key={i}>{item.item.name}</h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: it AN answer, not THE answer

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch("https://fortnite-api.theapinetwork.com/upcoming/get")
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data.data[0].item.name)
    }
```

For more insights, checkout my sandbox here : https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-haibt-i673h?file=/src/App.js:165-327

Comment: please don't answer questions where the (perhaps) useful information is in an external link that can easily "go stale" or "disappear" ... or worse